# Append within Multiple Arrays using Mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to handle list of friends or users which consists of comma separated ObjectID's of different users, now i have  **NetworkList** array which stores, list of users, so far i used $push to append list of ObjectID's in **NetworkList** array here:

**Model:**

```
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({
UserID: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
NetworkList: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
});
```

**Server Controller:**

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var query={'UserID': req.body.UserID};
    var update = {$push: {'NetworkList': req.body.FriendID}};
};
```

**Now my model is :**

```
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({

UserID: {
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'User'
},
NetworkList: [{
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'User'
}],

NetworkRequest: [{
to:[{
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'User'}],
from:[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
}]

});
```

and i want to append inside both array's NetworkRequest and NetworkList, so i tried to use $push with both like

**Server Controller:**

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {

var query={'UserID':req.body.UserID};

var update = {$push: {'NetworkRequest':{to: req.body.FriendID, from: req.body.McReg}, 'NetworkList': req.body.FriendID}};

Network.find(query,function(err,user){
console.log(user);
if (err) {
    return err;
} else {
    console.log('no error');
}
});

Network.update(update,function(err){

if (err) {
    return err;
} else {
    console.log('Updated');
}
});
```

**Document:**

```
{
NetworkList: [
ObjectId("5490098c9f2652f01b3f68df"),
ObjectId("5490195f5afa90e01b500c37"),
 ],
NetworkRequest: {
_id: ObjectId("54902e9375fff9b01a007516"),
from: [ObjectId("5490195f5afa90e01b500c37")],
to: [
  ObjectId("54883e606d574c000feccb08"),(//not able to append here)
]
},
UserID: ObjectId("5490195f5afa90e01b500c37"),
__v: 0,
_id: ObjectId("5490195f5afa90e01b500c38")
}
```

i used console.log(update); where i am able to get objectID's inside both array's, but finally values are not getting up to the database, where i am going wrong with $push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push inside sub Array, you should use dot operator for your NetworkRequest Array.

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
var query={'UserID':req.body.UserID};
var update = {$push: {'NetworkRequest.to': req.body.FriendID, 'NetworkRequest.from': req.body.McReg}, 'NetworkList': req.body.FriendID}};

Network.update(query,update,{upsert:true}function(err){

if (err) {
return err;
} else {
console.log('Updated');
}
});
}
```